# How to run Php7.0 and Php5.6 at the same time

Tags: phpmyadmin, php7, magento

PHPMyAdmin uses php7 and for Magento I require php5.6
if I remove php7, the PHPMyAdmin gives HTTP 500 error or sometimes only loads the PHP text, tried installing all the mods but no positive results
and with php7 Magento doesn't work

is there any way where both can run side by side ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you load pages from `/var/www/html` or the error is from `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: i can load pages from /var/www/html from php 7 but not with php5.6

Comment: if you have php5 installed run this `a2query -m php5` to check if php module is loaded. use `sudo` please

Comment: got this No module matches php5.6 (disabled by site administrator)

Comment: where are you trying install these `php` are you the owner of the system? If yes do `sudo a2enmod php5` and run the command again

Comment: yes im the owner and i did that now localhost/info.php loads and says php version 5.6 but in terminal it says php7.0 and phpmyadmin gives me HTTP 500 error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49513/discussion-between-george-and-bharat).